# Spring Data Couchbase Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I've hit the similar problem as described here: [MappingInstantiationException with a BigInteger field in Spring Data Couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671068/mappinginstantiationexception-with-a-biginteger-field-in-spring-data-couchbase)
, so I've tried to workaround the problem with solution suggested by @Simon Baslé. I've added following custom converters:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
@EnableCouchbaseAuditing
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    (...)

    @Override
    public CouchbaseCustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CouchbaseCustomConversions(
                Arrays.asList(BigDecimalToStringConverter.INSTANCE,
                        StringToBigDecimalConverter.INSTANCE));
    }

    @WritingConverter
    enum BigDecimalToStringConverter implements Converter<BigDecimal, String> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public String convert(BigDecimal source) {
            return source == null ? null : source.toString();
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    enum StringToBigDecimalConverter implements Converter<String, BigDecimal> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public BigDecimal convert(String source) {
            return StringUtils.isNotEmpty(source) ? new BigDecimal(source) : null;
        }
    }
}
```

But after applying this solution I am getting next exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type java.math.BigDecimal!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.access$400(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:869)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getValueInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:328)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.access$400(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:869)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getValueInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:328)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.access$400(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:869)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getValueInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:328)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.access$400(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:869)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getValueInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:328)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readCollection(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:710)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.access$400(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:869)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getValueInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:328)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.access$400(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:869)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getValueInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:328)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.mapToEntity(CouchbaseTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.findById(CouchbaseTemplate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.SimpleCouchbaseRepository.findById(SimpleCouchbaseRepository.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.SimpleCouchbaseRepository.findById(SimpleCouchbaseRepository.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.ViewPostProcessor$ViewInterceptor.invoke(ViewPostProcessor.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy162.findById(Unknown Source)
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the ticket for adding the default converter is still open, adding custom converters is the way to go for now.

Comment: I found a stack overflow question that may help -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002986/no-mapping-metadata-found-for-java-lang-object-couchbase)